# Add an animation to swipe gestures in Swift

Tags: swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a swipe gesture in my app that when you swipe, it changes the text on screen. How would I make it so it looks like it is sliding to the new text rather than just instantly changing the text?

Comment: zachlul, does my answer make sense??

Answer (score 0):

You could do one thing!!!add a view behind your gesture view ,that  view should look same as that of gesture View(should even have same text),and once after recognizing gesture bring that view in-front of your gesture view it should have old text(don't update the text) and update your gesture view's text ones it moves behind newly added view,  just change the frame of newly added view so that it gives a sliding kind of effect(change its width) once after the completing animation bring that view back to gesture view and change its frame to previous its previous value.

check this sample:

```
 func handleGesture(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    //bring background view to front
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.backGroundView)
    self.gestureView.userInteractionEnabled = false

    //capture its initialAutolayout constraint
    let backgroundViewSpaceConstarint  = self.backGroundViewLeftSpaceConstraint.constant
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: { [unowned self]() -> Void in
        self.someRandomValue++

        // update text label in gesture view which is behind background View
        self.gestureViewTextLabel.text = "swiped \(self.someRandomValue) times"

        //slide backgroundView in required direction by using autolayout
        self.backGroundViewLeftSpaceConstraint.constant = self.backGroundView.bounds.size.width
        self.backGroundView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { [unowned self](completion:Bool) -> Void in
            //after animation complition bring gesture view to the front.
            self.backgroundTextLabel.text =  "swiped \(self.someRandomValue) times"
            self.gestureView.userInteractionEnabled = true

            //upadte background view so that it will look the same for next swipe
            self.backGroundViewLeftSpaceConstraint.constant = backgroundViewSpaceConstarint
            //send the background view behind gesture view
            self.view.sendSubviewToBack(self.backGroundView)
          }
  }
```